# Can EA show the dependancies between packages like Visual Paradigm when reverse engineer Java code?

Tags: java, uml, package, enterprise-architect, visual-paradigm

I am trying to reverse engineer a java project from source code into UML with EnterpriseArchitect. I want to see the dependencies between packages and also how classes are grouped together into packages.

I have also used VisualParadigm to do the same. The image shows a small sample:

[image]

Can the same(or very close to the above image) result be achieved with EA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK EA will not create any package dependencies on RE. However, you can add those dependencies manually once the import is complete. Furthermore you can write a script that creates such dependencies automatically. I did so a couple of years ago. It was not too difficult - not trivial though :-)

Comment: since i am not that familiar with EA can you please point me to an example/tutorial to have a look?

Comment: You mean for the script? I'll have a look if I still can find it after all the years :P I'll update later. Time for bed now.

Comment: Well I don't mean your script but point me somewhere where I can see how to start working with scripts and eventually try to do something like you.

Comment: I've done this too, and have some vague thoughts on productizing it and selling it - it seems there's a need. Anyway, for general information on scripting, check the help file under Automation and Scripting -- Scripting.

Comment: I've been looking for the script but could not find it. Basically you scan all elements of a package and reflect a package dependency via elements connected to elements located in other packages. I guess you can create that within a day or so if you are familiar with the API.

Comment: OK.Thanks. I am not familiar with the API but it seems that I will need to start checking it after all.

Comment: Don't know if I should ask it here but: Why the need of using scripts? Why hasn't the process become automated yet? Why isn't there a default (minimal) script?

Comment: Like in most cases you need a) the idea b) the capacity and c) the hope to get a return on investment. Probably for EA it failed in one or more of that conditions. See my comment here: http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1420798882/0#1